# How I can load .owl file in Apache Jena triple store?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, triplestore

I have a file snomedct_owl.owl which is near about 215 MB in size. I installed Jena triple store and tried to upload this file to it, but the file is not getting uploaded. 
What should I do?

Comment: There's not enough information here to diagnose the problem (and by not using any of the Jena related tags, it's less likely that people with knowledge about Jena will see the question, so I've added some tags).  A file ending with .owl could be in lots of different formats (e.g., OWL functional syntax, OWL/XML, OWL serialized as RDF in RDF/XML, N3, Turtle, N-Triples, etc.).  It's not clear what you mean by "upload this file to it".  Please describe your problem in more detail, including what you've done and how.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Joshua. I appreciate your reply.
I want to load that .owl file (OWL/XML format) in Apache Jena Fuseki triple store.

Comment: I don't think that Jena supports OWL/XML, so you'll need to convert it to an RDF format first, and then you can load it into Jena. But, are you *sure* that's it's OWL/XML, and not RDF/XML?  In my experience, RDF/XML serializations of OWL ontologies are much more common than OWL/XML.

Comment: Yeah, the file was OWL/XML but now I changed it to RDF/XML. and tried to load it to Jena, every time I try to load it at the end Jena server automatically gets turned off before the loading process completes.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you're on the right track, but I think you'll need to provide a lot more detail before we can diagnose the problem.  For such a large file, you might want to load it incrementally, or use tdbloader on the server side.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Joshua for your help.